# nth entry matching the first quoted item in tuple

Tags: scala

I have a `List` that contains the tuple `(e:Int, a:String, b:String)` where `e` refers to eventid which will be increasing, `a` represents the first quoted item in the tuple and `b` represents the second one.

The list is sorted on the eventid and I need to get the nth entry of item a matching n.

```
val ad = List(( 10 ,"W","A"),( 20 ,"W","E"),( 30 ,"I","W"),( 40 ,"A","E"),( 50 ,"P","E"),
( 60 ,"S","A"),( 70 ,"A","P"),( 80 ,"A","I"),( 100 ,"A","S"),( 110 ,"I","S"),
( 120 ,"A","N"),( 130 ,"E","N"))
```

The expected result is

```
(1,W)
(1,I)
(1,P)
(1,S)
(2,A)
(4,E)
```

W appears in `a` for the first time against eventid=10 and it should be captured. Similarly for I, P, and S. A appears against eventid=20 in `b` but as first quoted again in eventid=40, so it should be captured as `(2,A)`. Similarly for E.

I'm trying the below code using `foldLeft` but getting errors and incorrect results.

```
val t = ( 1 until ad.size).map {
  p => {
    ad.foldLeft((List.empty[(Int, String)], Map[String, Int]().empty, Map[String, Int]().empty)) {
      case ((a, b, c), x) => {

        (a, x+ ( b, (b.getOrElse(x._2, 0) + 1),  x + (x._3 , (b.getOrElse(x._3, 0) + 1))
      }
    }._1
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(9, 8) ')' expected but '}' found.
      }
      ^
```

I'm struggling with `foldLeft` operation here, can this be fixed?.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
final case class Entry(eventId: Int, a: String, b: String)

def getNthEntry(data: List[Entry]): Map[String, Int] = {
  def getPlusOne(map: Map[String, Int], key: String): (String, Int) =
    key -> (map.getOrElse(key, default = 0) + 1)

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remeaining: List[Entry], acc: Map[String, Int], bCount: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] =
    remeaining match {
      case Nil =>
        acc

      case Entry(_, a, b) :: xs =>
        val newAcc = 
          if (acc.contains(a))
            acc
          else
            acc + getPlusOne(map = bCount, key = a)

        val newBCount =
          bCount + getPlusOne(map = bCount, key = b)

        loop(remeaining = xs, newAcc, newBCount)
    }

  loop(remeaining = data, acc = Map.empty, bCount = Map.empty)
}
```

***Note:** Technically, you can do exactly the same with `foldLeft`. However, IMHO, the hand made tail-recursive algorithm is easier to read*.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but it is not matching with expected results. it is giving ````Map(E -> 11, A -> 3, I -> 2, P -> 4, W -> 0, S -> 5)````

Comment: A already appeared in 'b' for eventid=10 for the first time and only in the second time when eventid=40 it appears in the first quoted item i.e in a.. so (2,A)..

Comment: there was an error and I wrapped one more brackets in your code to fix that ````(key -> (map.getOrElse(key, default = 0) + 1))```` and it works fine now.. which version do you use ?... thanks for the answer.

Comment: @stack0114106 Oh yeah, copy and paste error. I use `2.13` but this should work on `2.12` & `2.11` as far as I know. BTW, I am deleting old comments, since I feel they do not add to much after both read them.